# bind xPages combobox not working properly

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a simple combobox that is bind to some combobox field on Notes form.
The problem is that if I open a document with value that is not in the list it sets the xPage combobox to first available instead of blank. I.e. notes document has value e.g. "Done" in the field. But the combo shows "New" instead of blank when I open it in web.

```
<xp:comboBox value="#{document1.Status}" id="Status">
    <xp:selectItems id="selectItems1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var arr = new Array(" ");
            arr.push("New");    
            arr.push("Opne");   
            arr.push("Cancel"); 
            arr.push("In Progress");
            arr.push("Done");   

            return arr;
            }]]>
        </xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
</xp:comboBox>
```

Comment: Works well for me. I am on 9.0.1 FP9. My test: if documen's field Status has value "AAA" it shows up as empty value. That's what you expect, right?

Comment: It shows "New" for me on same 9.0.1 FP9

Comment: Test it with a new database and just the code above in an XPage. Does this work for you?